# Application specific environment variable settings

Tags: gnome, 9.10, emacs, environment-variables

I'm trying to work around a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/emacs23/+bug/581486) in Ubuntu 9.10, where using the scrollbar in emacs causes text to be highlighted, and the cursor to move. [This page here](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=4870) shows that you can fix this by setting an environment variable before launching emacs:

```
$ GDK_NATIVE_WINDOWS=1 emacs
```

So a lazy fix would be to alias "emacs" in my .bashrc:

```
alias emacs="GDK_NATIVE_WINDOWS=1 emacs"
```

This, however, has the drawback of setting this environment variable for all subsequent commands run from that shell. Is there any way to set `GDK_NATIVE_WINDOWS=1` for just emacs, whenever I run emacs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`env`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/env) command:

```
env GDK_NATIVE_WINDOWS=1 emacs
```

and you can alias this as before:

```
alias emacs="env GDK_NATIVE_WINDOWS=1 emacs"
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to clear the variable once emacs started. I am not sure how you can do this, however I am pretty sure it can be done.

Comment: So something like: alias emacs = "tmp=${GDK_NATIVE_WINDOWS} GDK_NATIVE_WINDOWS=1 emacs& GDK_NATIVE_WINDOWS=${tmp}" ?